# How to zoom Actor in ScrollPane in libGDX

Tags: android, libgdx

I have game field which is a Group with Actors. The Group locketed in Table wich is locketed in ScrollPane. I have two Buttons to zoom in and zoom out the game field. Here is my code how I do it:

```
    TextButton zoomInBtn = new TextButton("+", menuBtnStyle);
    zoomInBtn.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            float width = fieldGroup.getWidth();
            float height = fieldGroup.getHeight();
            float newWidth = width + width * 0.1f;
            if (newWidth > myWorld.getMaxWidth()) {
                newWidth = myWorld.getMaxWidth();
            }
            float newHeight = height * newWidth / width;
            fieldGroup.setWidth(newWidth);
            fieldGroup.setHeight(newHeight);
            myWorld.setWidth(Math.round(newWidth));
            fieldGroup.reinitialiseChildren();
            Cell cell = fieldTable.getCell(fieldGroup);
            cell.clearActor();
            cell.setActor(fieldGroup);
        }
    });
    TextButton zoomOutBtn = new TextButton("-", menuBtnStyle);
    zoomOutBtn.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            float width = fieldGroup.getWidth();
            float height = fieldGroup.getHeight();
            float newWidth = width - width * 0.1f;
            if (newWidth < myWorld.getMinWidth()) {
                newWidth = myWorld.getMinWidth();
            }
            float newHeight = height * newWidth / width;
            Actor widget = scrollPane.getWidget();

            fieldGroup.setWidth(newWidth);
            fieldGroup.setHeight(newHeight);
            myWorld.setWidth(Math.round(newWidth));
            fieldGroup.reinitialiseChildren();
            Cell cell = fieldTable.getCell(fieldGroup);
            cell.clearActor();
            cell.setActor(fieldGroup);
        }
    });
```

I change the size of my fieldGroup with Image Actors in it. And then readding it to Table.

The problem is: when I zoom with buttons it always zoom around left corner. I want it to zoom from canter of ScrollPane. I know that I can do it with Ortographic Camera, but it would be difficult, I think, to make it movements so smooth as ScrollPane. So maybe there is some way to do it with ScrollPane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you zoom in or out you would have to change the x and y position of the group relative to the zoom. You can do this using the `setScrollx` (and y) of your scroll pane.

You need to set so that the middle of the part you are viewing stays in the middle of the scrollpane. You can work out middle of newWidth by dividing it by 2. If the scrollPane is fullScreen you can half the value obtained by `Gdx.graphics.getwidth();`. The difference between these two is then the value which will keep the middles aligned.

```
newXvalue =(newWidth/2) - ((Gdx.graphics.getWidth())/2);
scrollPane.setScrollx(newXvalue);
```

The same should be done for y.

Note: if you want to zoom and move at same time, this will not work, I would recommend using orthographic camera with a gesture listener for that.

Comment: If I do that, I think that scrolling would not work correctly or it'll do nothing, because Table which contains my fieldGroup stores it in relative coordinates.

Comment: You could use scrollX instead of setX, thus only moving the group in the scroll pane

Comment: Thank you it is something. But I don't really understand what setScrollX do. Because when I do setScrollX(newXvalue) ScrollPane moves to the left edge.

Comment: For this it would have to be the other way around if you get me, you want to scroll to a Positive number, not set the x value to negative, if that makes sense. Hence: `newXvalue = (newWidth/2) - ((Gdx.graphics.getWidth())/2) ;`

I'll update my answer

Comment: I'll try it, but now I understand that the scrollPane would twitch even if I do everything else fine. So maybe I really need to use Orthographic Camera. But I don't understand how I can have my game field zoomable and movable by the camera, and have UI buttons around it at the same time.

Comment: I use two stages for mine, one for game (map which is scrolled and zoomed, and also map tiles which can be clicked), this is handled by a gesture listener. This stage then has an associated camera which is moved/zoomed. On top of this, there is another stage which has other information such as leaderboard which can be clicked on. The main benefit here is that the camera for the overlay stays in the same position. I then use an [inputMultiplexer](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputMultiplexer.html) to differentiate between the two.